# How to Find Area of a Triangle from $3$ sides

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

How would I find the area of a triangle, given $3$ side lengths $3$, $4$, and $6$?

Would there be any way to do this?

Comment: Have you heard of the Cosine rule? Or simply recognise that that is a pythagorean triple of a right angled triangle

Comment: I changed one of the lengths from 5 to 6.

Comment: [Heron's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron's_formula).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given 3 sides $A$, $B$, and $C$, you could use the [**Heron's Formula**](https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-find-the-area-of-a-triangle-with-3-sides-given) to obtain the lengths of the three sides.

However, I like this approach more, since you can easily understand it (although it is LONGER).

Follow **[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSP0F.jpg)** to see what I mean.

$AB=3$

$AC=4$

$BC=6$

Define side $AD$ (which is an altitude) as $x$, and side $BD$ as $y$.

Therefore, by the pythagorean theorem,

$$y^2+x^2=3^2$$$$(6-y)^2+x^2=4^2$$

Once you solve these two equations, you obtain $x$, which is the height of the triangle from the base $BC$. Now I think you know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Heron's formula gives that the area $A$ of a triangle of sides $a,b,c$ and semiperimeter $s = \frac 12(a+b+c)$ is $A = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$. Apply that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The formula for finding the area of a triangle is $A=\cfrac{bh}{2}$ where $b$ is the length of the base and $h$ is the height. If it is a right triangle, the height is easy. If not, you have to do some other geometry to find the height. Once you have the height from a particular base plug it into the formula. If it is not right comment on this and I will help you more!

Comment: I am sorry, I changed one of the side lengths from 5 to 6.

Answer (score 0):

Heron's formula would be the most direct $A  = \sqrt {s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$

$s = \frac{a+b+c}{2}$

$A  = \sqrt {\frac {13}{2}\frac {7}{2}\frac{5}{2}\frac {1}{2}} = \frac {\sqrt {455}}{4}$